# Integrate Views3 with Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I was told to integrate Views 3 with Drupal 7 following this tutorial:

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Views3+Integration

However, I do not have this:

```
You should see a page with output that begins with: "$databases['default']['default']['prefix']= array("
```

So I'd like to know if that tutorial doesn't apply anymore or what I need to do to get that PHP config to show.

This is a fresh installation so I'm using latest versions of Drupal and CiviCRM

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't see that screen in Karin's answer, here are some reasons why you might not ([source](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/d5568f72e268599a3d33493a9a833e83422fcc95/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/UF.php#L75)):

- You aren't using Drupal at all! Views and its integration won't work on your site at all then
- You have CiviCRM and Drupal in the same database. With a shared DB, no aliasing is required in `settings.php`, it'll work out of the box.
- You don't have Views enabled in Drupal yet. The screen won't show up until Views is enabled.

Comment: How can I know that this config succeeded?

Comment: Make a view that shows some data 

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to CiviCRM -> Administer -> System Settings -> CMS Database Integration:

[image]

Copy all of that... into the Drupal settings.php file for your site!

Comment: Yes, I'm right there! But I don't have any content after Save and Cancel buttons